# Visual Studio 2019 editor destroys Linux soft link from Samba share, how to avoid this bad behavior?

Tags: visual-studio-2019, samba

This is an annoying problem. Let me elaborate it.

Environment:

- I have a Ubuntu 20.04 Linux machine which have some C/C++ code in `/home/chj/gitw/bookcode-linux/TLPI`, some .c file(e.g. `$TLPI/lib/become_daemon.c`) is actually a soft link that links to actual file `$TLPI/daemons/become_daemon.c`.
- The Linux machine runs Samba server so that a Samba client can access the files there.
- I have another machine running Win10.22H2, it uses `net use L: \\10.22.3.213\chj /user:chj ******` so that the `become_daemon.c` is accessible from this Windows PC as `L:\gitw\bookcode-linux\TLPI\lib\become_daemon.c`.
- This Win10 PC runs VS2019 16.11, and have it open and edit `L:\gitw\bookcode-linux\TLPI\lib\become_daemon.c`.

Now the bad thing happens. After VS2019 edits and saves the become_daemon.c file, the soft link at Linux side is destroyed. The `$TLPI/lib/become_daemon.c` becomes a normal file.

[image]

That is really not my desired behavior. I hope that `$TLPI/daemons/become_daemon.c` is changed after VS2019's editing, but not the soft link node itself.

I've written a simple program on Windows to `CreateFile()`, `WriteFile()`, `CloseHandle()` on `L:\gitw\bookcode-linux\TLPI\lib\become_daemon.c`, and see that the soft link is preserved.

ProcessMonitor reveals that VSIDE is actually creating a temp file to store my editd text, then rename(+overwrite) it to be the final `become_daemon.c`.

[image]

> SetRenameInformationFile
>
> ReplaceIfExists: True, FileName: \10.22.3.213\chj\gitw\bookcode-linux\TLPI\lib\become_daemon.c~RF321c0a07.TMP

Ouch, no wonder the soft link is overwritten to become a normal file.

Then I'd really want to ask, is there any way I can tell Visual Studio not to use a temp file and operate(`WriteFile()`) on the target file directly.